# Console game Character

Tags: c#, ascii, console-application

Since the beginning of developing my game, I've learned a lot. Now I'm at a stage where I need to get a proper player character implemented. I've been trying to do so for a while now, but I can't get it to work with my movement system. This is my movement system (with collision):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    switch (input.KeyChar)
                    {
                        case 'w':
                            if (y >= 1 && data[y - 1][x] != '#')
                            {
                                oldx = Console.CursorLeft;
                                oldy = Console.CursorTop;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, y - 1);
                                x = Console.CursorLeft;
                                y = Console.CursorTop;
                                //if (x == 11 && y == 11 )            
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'a':
                            if (x >= 1 && data[y][x - 1] != '#')
                            {
                                oldx = Console.CursorLeft;
                                oldy = Console.CursorTop;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 1, y + 0);
                                x = Console.CursorLeft;
                                y = Console.CursorTop;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 's':
                            if (y < Console.WindowHeight - 1 && data[y + 1][x] != '#')
                            {
                                oldx = Console.CursorLeft;
                                oldy = Console.CursorTop;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 0, y + 1);
                                x = Console.CursorLeft;
                                y = Console.CursorTop;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'd':
                            if (x < Console.WindowWidth - 1 && data[y][x + 1] != '#')
                            {
                                oldx = Console.CursorLeft;
                                oldy = Console.CursorTop;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 1, y + 0);
                                x = Console.CursorLeft;
                                y = Console.CursorTop;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
```

My map is an ascii map, displayed in the colors that ConsoleColor has to offer. Behind the player character, the corresponding map tile should be redrawn, without redrawing the entire map (having to do so is really annoying during gameplay)

When you exit the map, a new map will be drawn and the player is teleported to the entrance of that map.

How would I implement the drawing of a character as a subroutine?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can set the cursor position, but yeah this is a bit hacky

Comment: @TheGeneral Hmm, actually yes, if set cursor position and write smth it'll update a few chars

Answer (score 0):

Give these a try

```
protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
       Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol+x, origRow+y);
       Console.Write(s);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
       Console.Clear();
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

[Console.CursorTop Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cursortop?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_CursorTop)

> Gets or sets the row position of the cursor within the buffer area.

[Console.CursorLeft Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cursorleft?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets or sets the column position of the cursor within the buffer area.

[Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Sets the position of the cursor.